# Making a bootable windows 7 installation flashdrive from Fedora

Tags: usb-flash-drive, fedora, windows-installation

My main rig had Windows go down and all I have is a blank flashdrive and a netbok with fedora running on it.  I have the windows 7 iso ready to go.  I tried unetbootin, but all I got was a blank boot menu.

Comment: Did you set the boot flag for the USB drive? That could be why you don't see any boot options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I've used UNetbootin lots of times to create Linux LiveUSBs, I've never used it to transfer Windows setup to USB. Doesn't seem to be one of the things it's supposed to support, but maybe it has worked for some people.

Here's a slightly more lengthy process you can try, but it should work fine:

1. Download and install [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net) if you don't have it already
2. Ideally, delete all existing partitions on your USB drive, then create a new partition, format as NTFS and set the **boot** flag from the **Manage Flags** dialog:

   [image]
   [image]
3. Download and install [ms-sys](http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net)
4. Enter `su ms-sys -7 /dev/sdX` at the terminal to write a Windows 7 MBR to your USB drive
   (where 'X' is your USB drive letter)
5. Mount your Windows 7 ISO and copy all the files to the USB drive
6. Boot from the USB drive and test

Comment: does not work. used xcdroast and dvdrw instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Diskpart` utility to format the USB flash drive to NTFS and create a primary partition. Note that you also need to make the USB bootable, in addition to copying the files, as mentioned [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Bootable-Windows-7-or-Vista-USB-Drive).

Comment: Diskpart is available on Fedora? Since when?