# Unable to create Windows 10 usb boot stick with fedora

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, usb

I tried many different ways of creating a 64bit [Windows 10 Boot Image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) with a USB drive using my laptop with Fedora 28. However, everything I tried failed.

Using either [GNOME MultiWriter](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-multi-writer) or `dd` left me with no option to boot from the usb device in UEFI.

[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), [woeusb](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB) or [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) all left me with the ability to select the USB boot option in UEFI, enter the installation manager of Windows, but after choosing the language and starting the setup, it loads and fails with an error saying it could not find `C:\sources\install.wim`. I double- and triple-checked that it *is* there, but for some reason, Windows cannot find it. Thus, [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-install-cannot-find-installwim/3e7e2bd5-ed31-4834-bd09-d55bf0391ca0) answer on the Microsoft forums does not help, either. This also happens when I manually partition the stick as described [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/743825/315793).

I also tried using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en_IE.html) with Wine, but it does not detect the USB drive.

My USB drive has 32 GB and is a USB 3.0 drive. I used it before to install Fedora on the very same laptop. I also tried using a USB 2.0 drive (also used to install other OSes in the past) just in case, but to no avail; the same error message about `install.wim` occurred.

I also downloaded the Windows 10 image again, in case of any corruption and verified the md5 sum to be exactly the same between both donwloads.

I don't know what else to do. Does anybody know about this error with `install.wim`? I was unable to find any additional information about this error. When I look at the file inside Nautilus on the drive, I'm a bit surprised to find it being 4.3 GB in size. The stick being formatted as FAT32, I thought there couldn't be any files greater in size than 4 GB.

Answer (score 0):

did u format ur USB to FAT 32 firsts
u can fomat via app DISKS .. then right click gear tol format to select FAT
note:..u should format olnly one whole partition

to do this open gpartitioln and selct right click USB AFTER DEVICES... UCAN DELETE PARTIONS to single partition folr folrmatting/.... or right click thhe device... press unmollunt>>> then format to FAT32

also try woesUSB or multiwriter... ireccomend multiwriter in the software app

then i reccomend boot mode check tol see which olne works/// shoul;d be legacy///UIE boolt mades..

be sure to xheck this method

Comment: nolte;;; check the checkmark in gpartition and selct apply to actually apply the settings every time in the popup screen after sel;ecting the checkmark